# Setting webserver my site in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I need to set a web server for running my ASP site.(Windows XP)

I placed my compleate site in c:inetpub ->wwwroot.

Sorry for the delay..

IIS is already there but below error is showing.

Error Type:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80004005)
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
/dev-ehr/Connections/eHR.asp, line 4

Browser Type:
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)

Page:
GET /dev-ehr/login.asp

Now I added connection string in Datasource ODBC.Now when I run localhost ,Iam getting an error

"an error occured in dllhost.exe[300]"

Can help to solve this..

Comment: .. and your question is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to isntall IIS:
[Install IIS on XP](http://www.webwizguide.com/kb/asp_tutorials/installing_iis_winXP_pro.asp)